# error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number' with cl.exe vc compiler

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

The code fragment I try to compile looks like this

```
VOID
PTSetPageAttributexxyy (  
  IN UINT64                     2g,
  IN UINT64                     Base,
  IN UINT64                     Length,
  IN UINT32                     Ra,
  IN UINT32                     Wa,
  IN UINT32                     Xa,
  IN MY_ATTRIBUTE_SETTING setting
    );
```

I get:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
```

with cl.exe vc compiler

Comment: What's `2g` and what is it doing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter name `2g` is not valid. It must begin with a letter or `_`.

Comment: got something like that by using capital `O` instead of `zero` (e.g. `0xCOOL` instead of `0xC001` o_O time for `0xCAFE`)